# C# Background worker parameter problem?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am calling this zip_threading class in another class. string a = zip_threading(?,?)but the problem is that how can i pass the parameter values when i am calling this class which are : String [] files, bool IsOriginal. i have used in this class background worker threading, so the real problem is that passing the value to this class and then return a value when processing is finished in make_zip_file class.

```
public class zip_threading
```

{

```
public string[] files { get; set; } // to be recieved by the zip method as zip file names.
public int number;
public string return_path;
public bool IsOriginal { get; set; }  // to be recieved by the zip method as boolean true or fales
public static BackgroundWorker bgw1 = new BackgroundWorker(); // make a background worker object.
public void bgw1_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    make_zip_file mzf1 = e.Result as make_zip_file;
    return_path = mzf1.return_path;

}
public make_zip_file bgw_DoWork(string[] files, bool IsOriginal, make_zip_file argumentest)
{

    Thread.Sleep(100);
    argumentest.return_path = argumentest.Makezipfile(files,IsOriginal);
    return argumentest;

}
public void run_async(string []files,bool IsOriginal)
{

    make_zip_file mzf2 = new make_zip_file();
   // mzf2.files = files;
    //mzf2.IsOriginal = IsOriginal;

    bgw1.DoWork += (sender, e) => e.Result = bgw_DoWork(files, IsOriginal, mzf2);
    bgw1.RunWorkerAsync();
```

}

```
public  class make_zip_file
    {

 public string return_path ;
        //public string[] files{get;set;}
       // public bool IsOriginal{get;set;}


    public string Makezipfile(string[] files, bool IsOriginal)
    {

        string[] filenames = new string[files.Length];
        if (IsOriginal)
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                ***filenames[i] = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Remove(0, 10).ToString();***
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                ***filenames[i] = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), "");***
        string DirectoryName = filenames[0].Remove(filenames[0].LastIndexOf('/'));
        DirectoryName = DirectoryName.Substring(DirectoryName.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).Replace("\\", "");

        try
        {

            string newFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "images\\Thumbnails\\zipFiles\\" + DirectoryName + ".zip";
            if (File.Exists(newFile))
                File.Delete(newFile);
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {

                foreach (string file in filenames)
                {

                    string newfileName = file.Replace("\\'", "'");
                    zip.CompressionLevel = 0;
                    zip.AddFile(newfileName, "");
                }

                zip.Save(newFile);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception during processing {0}", ex);

            // No need to rethrow the exception as for our purposes its handled.
        }

        return_path = "images/Thumbnails/zipFiles/" + DirectoryName + ".zip";
return return_path;
}}
```

now i am calling this method in other class: like this

```
String path=zipa.run_async(fileCollection, IsOriginal);
```

I get error in make_Zip_File, and i mark that with : Object reference not set to an Instance of an object* filenames[i] = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Remove(0, 10).ToString();*

Answer (score 1):

By taking this to a different thread, you are running *outside* of the http-context, which may well finish long before your zip operation does (tearing down all the things like inbound stream buffers) - yet you are talking to `HttpContext.Current`.

You have a few options; thinking off the top of my head...

- run it on the request thread; it'll take a while, but meh...
- buffer all the data you need in memory, and pass that to the zip operation
- write the file to disk in a temp area (not the main app folder) from the request thread, then spawn a separate thread to process it from the temp area

but to re-iterate: you can't access the request from another thread - or at least, you shouldn't.

Also, consider:

- a request starts
- you spin up a thread to do the zip
- you return from the original request
- (worker thread keeps on going)

you need to think about what you are going to do with the zip filename; you can't just give it to the client - they are no longer listening to you.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Thanks for your suggestion and they seem to be solid but currently i have to rely on this one, and give me some idea or solution that why is data not passed to the method?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: the zip files are large in size like 500 MB so that is why i am running it in the background.

Comment: @safi - that doesn't change the way that the http request/response cycle works

Comment: @Marc Gravell: yes i know but instead of showing a busy screen to user, i think its good to run it in the background and user continue his work.

Comment: @safi - fine, but you can't keep reading from a request stream that **no longer exists**

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Can you suggest me a sloution in the current context ?

Comment: You mean other than the two above? (not counting the "do it in the current request"). But it sounds like in reality you are still waiting on the incoming request. If that is simply too big, I'm not sure you are going to be able to do anything hugely to make it return immediately for them; http just doesn't work like that. Is something like Silverlight an option? You could write a silverlight tool that chunks the file and uploads portions, for example. Or there is a flash uploader that worked well.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: yes, other than the above, yes you are right i am waiting for some incoming request but still the user do not know as the work in fore-ground. In this case i am downloading the file, I am using AJAX, XML, aSP.NET and c#.

Comment: @safi if you are handling the async at the client, why do you need to thread at the server too?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: tell me i am waiting for some suggestion, in this case if i am using AJAX then what should i do?

Comment: @safi - there isn't any simple solution for a 500MB upload. Since you are using ajax, it isn't clear to me what the scenario is that you're trying to help, i.e. what goes wrong if you just run it from the request thread. But... 500MB; ouch. Http is a PITA for that.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I have large size images on server, so if user can select multiple files to download them as zip, the size can grow upto 500 or even more, so the zipping of such file on server take longer, and the screen of the user become irresponse. for this purpose i wanted to run the zipping in the background, and when zipping is completed its downloaded automatically. I hope you understand the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Check files[i]  is intialized or not since it is coming from somewhere to the function

```
Makezipfile(string[] files, bool IsOriginal)
{

}
```

i think there will be no value in it.

Comment: Das:yes this is the main problem i am passing value to it, but it give this null object reference error, so i think there is a problem in the threading but cant fix it:(